# Access VBA for loop refer to variable using i

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop

I have a macro in Access 2016 using a for loop to check the values of check boxes. I want to submit the values to a table.
I don't want the standard checkbox value for true (-1) I want the value of a 'rolling' count of which has been checked.

e.g.
CB1
CB2
CB3
CB4

If only CB1 and CB4 are checked then I want to submit to the table the values 1 for CB1 and 2 for CB4.

My for loop is:

```
For i = 1 To 8
If Me.Controls("CP" & i) = -1 Then
"CP" & i = I    'ISSUE IS HERE
Debug.Print Me.Controls("CP" & i)
End If
Next i
```

How do I refer to the variable value? so CP & I = CP1, CP2, CP3, CP4 etc...

Comment: `Me.Controls("CP" & i)= I`?

Answer (score 1):

variable names, are static you cannot use the syntax "CP" & i to access a variable. you have to use array instead.

```
Dim arrCP(8)
For i=Me.controls("CP" & i)=-1 then
arrCP(i)=i
debug.print arrCP(i)
end if
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, using a `countTrue` to determine the number you would like to display.

```
Dim countTrue As Long: countTrue = 0
For i = 1 To 8
    If Me.Controls("CP" & i) = -1 Then
        countTrue = countTrue + 1
        Me.Controls("CP" & i) = countTrue
        Debug.Print Me.Controls("CP" & i)
    End If
Next i
```